# Nested loop output to a data.frame

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I have two datasets in R (these tables below are just smaller versions) that I would like to combine into a new data frame.

```
> meetingtime2     
#two columns of datetime that class=factor

               ST                  ET
1 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
2 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
3 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00
4 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00
5 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00

> roomdata2 
#three columns; Room=factor, Capacity=integer, Video Conference=numeric

   Room Capacity Video.Conference
1 0M02A       16                1
2 0M03A        8                0
3 0M03B       12                1
```

The desired output would be a 15 row by 5 column matrix. In easy speak the output is every time slot for every room.

```
#the following is a MANUALLY created output of what the first few rows should look like

    Room Capacity Video.Conference        ST                ET
 1 0M02A   16           1       2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
 2 0M02A   16           1       2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
 3 0M02A   16           1       2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00
 4 0M02A   16           1       2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00
 5 0M02A   16           1       2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00
 6 0M03A   16           1       2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
 7 0M03A   16           1       2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
#and so forth to 15 rows.
```

I've tried using a nested loop

```
#note, the code is written so I can apply to a bigger (1000's of rows) dataset

 >mylist<-list() 
 >for(i in 1:(nrow(roomdata2)))   
   +{   for(j in 1:(nrow(meetingtime2)))   
 +mylist[[j]]<-      data.frame(roomdata2[i,1],roomdata2[i,2],roomdata2[i,3],
 +meetingtime2[j,1],meetingtime2[j,2])  
  } 
   >df<-do.call("rbind",mylist)  
>df
```

The output I get. I'm getting all the timeslots for the last room, just not the preceding rooms

```
roomdata2.i..1. roomdata2.i..2. roomdata2.i..3.  meetingtime2.j..1.  meetingtime2.j..2.
1    0M03B          12             1         2014-12-22 07:00:00    2014-12-22 07:30:00
2    0M03B          12             1         2014-12-22 07:30:00    2014-12-22 08:00:00
3    0M03B          12             1         2014-12-22 08:00:00    2014-12-22 08:30:00
4    0M03B          12             1         2014-12-22 08:30:00    2014-12-22 09:00:00
5    0M03B          12             1         2014-12-22 09:00:00    2014-12-22 09:30:00
```

I know my code is far from correct and is giving me the final iteration of the loop.

The other way I looked at this was a continuous print function for each iteration

```
 >for(i in 1:(nrow(roomdata2))) 
 >for(j in 1:(nrow(meetingtime2))) 
 >print(paste(roomdata2[i,1],roomdata2[i,2],roomdata2[i,3],
 +meetingtime2[j,1],meetingtime2[j,2]))
```

the output

```
 [1] "0M02A 16 1 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00"
 [1] "0M02A 16 1 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00"
 [1] "0M02A 16 1 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00"
 [1] "0M02A 16 1 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00"
 [1] "0M02A 16 1 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00"
 [1] "0M03A 8 0 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00"
 [1] "0M03A 8 0 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00"
 [1] "0M03A 8 0 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00"
 [1] "0M03A 8 0 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00"
 [1] "0M03A 8 0 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00"
 [1] "0M03B 12 1 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00"
 [1] "0M03B 12 1 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00"
 [1] "0M03B 12 1 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00"
 [1] "0M03B 12 1 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00"
 [1] "0M03B 12 1 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00"

#however the values are not separated, they are just in one set of string for each row.
```

The desired result is a table like directly above, but instead a dataframe with each value in a seperate column (each date & time set together in one column).

I've looked into lists,lapply,foreach but I just can't wrap my head around the solution.
Any help would be appreciated, I'm a beginner so I'm keen to learn.

Cheers
* the dputs

```
>dput(meetingtime2)
```

structure(list(ST = structure(1:5, .Label = c("22/12/2014 7:00", 
"22/12/2014 7:30", "22/12/2014 8:00", "22/12/2014 8:30", "22/12/2014 9:00"
), class = "factor"), ET = structure(1:5, .Label = c("22/12/2014 7:30", 
"22/12/2014 8:00", "22/12/2014 8:30", "22/12/2014 9:00", "22/12/2014 9:30"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ST", "ET"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

```
>dput(roomdata2)
```

structure(list(Room = structure(1:3, .Label = c("0M02A", "0M03A", 
"0M03B"), class = "factor"), Capacity = c(16L, 8L, 12L), Video.Conference = c(1L, 
0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Room", "Capacity", "Video.Conference"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you put the outputs of `dput(meetingtime2)` and `dput(roomdata2)` in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your data:

```
meetingtime2 <- read.csv(text = "ST,ET
2014-12-22 07:00:00,2014-12-22 07:30:00
2014-12-22 07:30:00,2014-12-22 08:00:00
2014-12-22 08:00:00,2014-12-22 08:30:00
2014-12-22 08:30:00,2014-12-22 09:00:00
2014-12-22 09:00:00,2014-12-22 09:30:00")

roomdata2 <- read.csv(text = "Room,Capacity,Video_Conference
0M02A,16,1
0M03A,8,0
0M03B,12,1")
```

Then `merge` handily returns the Cartesian product, because none of the columns match.

```
merge(meetingtime2, roomdata2)[, c(3:5, 1:2)]

##     Room Capacity Video_Conference                  ST                  ET
## 1  0M02A       16                1 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
## 2  0M02A       16                1 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
## 3  0M02A       16                1 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00
## 4  0M02A       16                1 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00
## 5  0M02A       16                1 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00
```

Comment: The results may not be ordered in the way the OP intended, however.

Comment: This is fantastically simple, I would never have guessed this. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but should get the job done. Given the following data:

```
ST <- c('2014-12-22 07:00:00', '2014-12-22 07:30:00', '2014-12-22 08:00:00', '2014-12-22 08:30:00', '2014-12-22 09:00:00')
ET <- c('2014-12-22 07:30:00', '2014-12-22 08:00:00', '2014-12-22 08:30:00', '2014-12-22 09:00:00', '2014-12-22 09:30:00')

RoomName <- c('0M02A', '0M03A', '0M03B')
Capacity <- c(16, 8, 12)
VideoCap <- c(1, 0, 1)

Times <- data.frame(ST, ET, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Rooms <- data.frame(RoomName, Capacity, VideoCap,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

the function below should do what you want:

```
Smash <- function(DF1, DF2){
  nm <- dim(DF1)
  pq <- dim(DF2)    
  maxrow <- nm[[1]] * pq[[1]]
  maxcol <- nm[[2]] + pq[[2]]
  MAT <- matrix('A', nrow = maxrow, ncol = maxcol)
  currow <- 1
    for (i1 in seq_len(nm[[1]])) {
      for (i2 in seq_len(pq[[1]])) {
        curcol <- 1
        for (j in seq_len(nm[[2]])) {
          MAT[currow, curcol] <- DF1[i1, j]
          curcol <- curcol + 1
        }
        for (j in seq_len(pq[[2]])) {
          MAT[currow, curcol] <- DF2[i2, j]
          curcol <- curcol + 1
        }
        currow <- currow + 1
      }
    }
  DF <- data.frame(MAT)
  names(DF) <- c(names(DF1), names(DF2))
  return(DF)
}
```

Smash(Rooms, Times) returns:

```
> Smash(Rooms, Times)
   RoomName Capacity VideoCap                  ST                  ET
1     0M02A       16        1 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
2     0M02A       16        1 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
3     0M02A       16        1 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00
4     0M02A       16        1 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00
5     0M02A       16        1 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00
6     0M03A        8        0 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
7     0M03A        8        0 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
8     0M03A        8        0 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00
9     0M03A        8        0 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00
10    0M03A        8        0 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00
11    0M03B       12        1 2014-12-22 07:00:00 2014-12-22 07:30:00
12    0M03B       12        1 2014-12-22 07:30:00 2014-12-22 08:00:00
13    0M03B       12        1 2014-12-22 08:00:00 2014-12-22 08:30:00
14    0M03B       12        1 2014-12-22 08:30:00 2014-12-22 09:00:00
15    0M03B       12        1 2014-12-22 09:00:00 2014-12-22 09:30:00
```

Comment: I'll trial this out, might be more robust than cartesian product